SSH login fails with "Permission denied" error after upgrading Debian from Bullseye to Bookworm
I am unable to SSH into my Debian server after upgrading from Bullseye to Bookworm. I have tried various troubleshooting steps, but the issue persists.
Error message:
Last login: Wed Apr 10 13:42:16 2024 from 192.168.x.x
The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
/usr/bin/sh: Permission denied

Troubleshooting steps taken:

Purged sshd from the machine and reinstalled openssh-server.
Set the sshd_config to a completely blank configuration, using only defaults.
Attempted to SSH into the server locally using ssh user@localhost, but encountered the same error.
Tried different default shells (e.g., /usr/bin/bash), but received similar "Permission denied" errors.
Attempted to log in as different users, including root, but the issue persisted.
Verified that /etc/shells contains the correct shell paths (/usr/bin/bash, /usr/bin/sh, etc.).
Checked permissions of home directory and .ssh directory, which appear to be normal.
Removed authorized_keys file to rule out any issues with key-based authentication.

Additional information:

I can log in successfully when accessing the server locally, both as root and as a regular user.
The /var/log/auth.log file shows "Accepted password for ..." followed by "Received disconnect from ...:disconnected by user".

System details:

Debian version: Bookworm (upgraded from Bullseye)
OpenSSH server version: OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2+deb12u2, OpenSSL 3.0.11 19 Sep 2023

setatus gives:
SELinux status: disabled
I have exhausted my troubleshooting ideas and would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this SSH login issue. Please let me know if you need any further information.

The issue might stem from outdated or misconfigured AppArmor profiles, affecting the sshd process in Debian Bookworm. To fix it:

Verify AppArmor's status with aa-status. If sshd is in "enforce" mode, AppArmor is actively applying policies on the SSH daemon.
Delete current AppArmor profiles using sudo rm -fr /etc/apparmor.d.
Reinstall AppArmor with sudo apt-get install apparmor for updated profiles.
Restart the SSH service with sudo systemctl restart ssh.

This should resolve any SSH login issues. Note: This method removes all AppArmor profiles. If you have custom profiles or wish to keep some, consider updating specific profiles instead.
